# Can't get past the ubuntu loading screen

Tags: laptop

When I try to get onto my laptop it stays at the ubuntu loading page with a flashing `_` at the top left corner.

I pressed ESC and it halts at this:

```
stopping send an event to indicate plymouth is up
```